# Independent Indexes in Elastic Search

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, tire

***UPDATE:** Redefined what I am trying to do.*

I have a model of Contact, this contact belongs to an account as does every other model in my account. I need all searches whether they be global or model specific to only query the containing account. I was told that I could do this with custom index names. I would like the index name to be the 'index-#{account-id}'. How would I achieve this in my active-models?

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  belongs_to :account

  mapping do
    indexes :first_name
    indexed :last_name
  end    

end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :contacts
end
```

Comment: define `contact` in ES to have a field `firmid` and filter on that? Otherwise I'm not sure what you're asking

Comment: does the update make better sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you refer to having each account (user?) physically separate in each it's own index? This is generally referred to as 'multi-tenant' http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy

Assuming this is indeed what you set out to do:

Much has been said in the past about the 'need' (I assume you want this for security reasons, I'm not familiar with other reasons why you would want this although I'm not an expert with multi-tenancy apps) for partitioning data per account/user, as apposed to just having, say,  a field `accountid` for `Contact` and be sure all your queries filter, at least, on `accountid`. IMO, a carefully designed query-component where, say, every query used in the system inherits from a 'super-query' which is required to set `accountid` would suffice in a lot of cases.

Even if you don't know upfront what apps in the future will want to query these indices, you could still enforce the above by say, having a thin REST-service around ES and require all programs to interact with ES through this service. You could then have this service handle this type of security by enforcing an `accountid` or, probably better, by inferring the `accountid` by the current logged-in user doing the request.

If you still want to pursue Multi-tenancy have a look at: http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Multi-tenacy-td471400.html (quickly searched this, perhaps there's better stuff around) 'Kimchy' (the creator of ES) comments in that thread as well.

Regardless, the best way in ES to have multi-tenancy is probably to have 1 index per account/user . Within that you could have multiple 'types' (an ES construct) , where `Contact` could be such a type.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/indices-types.html

Enforcing this in your models, as you are suggesting, is probably not the correct way IMO. Generally, you should keep your domain-models clean from any knowledge on the storage backend (including the index in which the data is stored)

To me, a better solution would be to have, as earlier suggested, a query-component in which the logic of choosing the correct index based on account/user would be contained. Going with the rest-service approach above, the dynamic indexname, as you suggested, could be derived from the logged-in user doing the request.

I realize that this probably wasn't a straight answer to your question, but I hope it was useful nonetheless.

Comment: It is a great answer. I could build this directly with the est interface. I am however using the 'tire' gem to communicate with ES. I was hoping there was some straight forward way to do it with the gem.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check this [comment at Tire's issues](https://github.com/karmi/tire/pull/92#issuecomment-6929988), which basically walks through some possible scenarios of the “tenant-based” index naming with Tire. I believe it's what you're after.

In elasticsearch itself, you have the option to have a separate index for every account, a filtered & routed index alias for every account, index templates, etc etc., so the toolkit is vast in this area.